# Search for a character in a string and then add a string before that character

Tags: java, string

I have a string that looks something like:

```
10.20.30.444,10.20.30.555,10.20.600.300
```

Now, I want to search for all the commas in the string and would like to add [2000] before the comma as well as in the last position. Now for the above string it would be like:

```
10.20.30.444[2000],10.20.30.444[2000],10.20.600.300[2000]
```

How can I achieve this in Java?

I would really appreciate a helping hand here.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It's best if you try it yourself first and ask stackoverflow users what is wrong with your code rather than asking for a complete answer from scratch

Answer (score 1):

use String.indexOf(",") in a loop then to insert 2000
for example if index returns 4
x = x.substring(0, 4) + "2000" + x.substring(4, x.length());
and do this in a loop

Comment: Just curious why this solution instead of String.replace()?

Comment: That's the penalty for his laziness!

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(",","[2000],");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace all commas with **[2000],** and append **[2000]** at the end that's all

```
String sometext ="10.20.30.444,10.20.30.555,10.20.600.300";
sometext=sometext.replaceAll(",", "[2000],")+"[2000]";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `StringBuilder` for this. `String replace()` creates a new String object each time you call it. `StringBuilder` does not, but I use two `StringBuilder` objects below.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("10.20.30.444,10.20.30.555,10.20.600.300");
    System.out.println(sb);
    StringBuilder sbnew = new StringBuilder();
    char c;
    for (int i=0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        c = sb.charAt(i);
        if (c == ',') {
            sbnew.append("[2000]");
        }
        sbnew.append(c);
    }
    sbnew.append("[2000]");
    System.out.println(sbnew);
```